# Элемент richTextBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Я в элементе `RichTextBox` не нашёл свойства `Legth`, как его можно вывести, к примеру, на `Label`?

И почему в *WPF* нет половины даже тех элементов, что есть в *WinForms*? Ведь там есть тоже нужные элементы, которые хотелось использовать в *WPF* приложениях.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы получить длину текста, содержащегося в RichTextbox, необходимо получить сам текст и взять его длину.

```
int GetLength(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    var textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

    return textRange.Text.Length;
}
```

Все контролы из Windos Forms доступны в WPF, поэтому при необходимости вы всегда можете использовать их.

Comment: И ещё вопрос, почему в WPF нету уже привычных свойств к примеру таких как richTextBox.Length или numericUpDown.Value и.т.д как без них?

Answer (score 0):

1. У `RichTextBox` есть свойство `TextLength`. С помощью него вы может узнать длину строки.
2. По поводу той проблемы что половина контролов с WinForms отсутсвтвует откладывает свой отпечаток, но есть и преймущество - нужный вам контрол довольно просто создать. Так же легко расширить функциональность текущих контрол, что допустим в WinForms было проблематично